# Annotate every Value in stacked column in google charts

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to create an chart with google charts like:
[stacked column chart with annotations in every value field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4uIQ.png).
Instead of the value it should show the name on every Value box in the stacked columns.

Name is always one row before the data in the google sheet - the data from google sheets can also be formated differently.

the posted code already does that, but only uses the same names for all rows instead of the custom names for every row/column.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var query = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fUeGQpVGXpXmQ6QLLBgMf3VpaYuOnQIX24lBGgG7yoQ/gviz/tq?range=1:24");
            query.send(handleQueryResponse);
        }

        function handleQueryResponse(response) {
            var data = response.getDataTable();
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart'));

            var options = {
                width: 1920,
                height: 1080,
                legend: { position: 'none' },
                column: { groupWidth: '95%' },
                isStacked: true
            };

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="columnchart" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

(if the google sheet link won't work, here is the [raw data](https://pastebin.com/raw/kkrxGieK))

Working code without google sheets (and minimal data, other label names):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['API Category', 
                        'Social', { role: 'annotation' }, 
                        'Music', { role: 'annotation' }, 
                        'File Sharing', { role: 'annotation' }, 
                        'Storage', { role: 'annotation' },
                        'Weather', { role: 'annotation' } 
                    ],
                    ['2011', 98, 'Uschi', 53, 'Petra', 12, 'Max', 16, 'Mustermann', 6, 'Siegfried'],
                    ['2012', 151, 'Susi', 34, 'Stackoverflow', 26, 'factor', 36, 'Ohnezahn', 49, 'Zahlos'],
                    ['2013', 69, 'Rick', 27, 'Rolled', 22, 'Visual', 17, 'Studio', 15, 'Code'],
                ]);

                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);



                var options = {
                    width: 1920,
                    height: 1080,
                    legend: { position: 'none' },
                    column: { groupWidth: '95%' },
                    isStacked: true
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("barchart_values"));
                chart.draw(view, options);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="barchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

It s probably possible to accomplish that with [Setcolumns() or setRows()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) but I just cannot wrap my head around it right now.

Maybe the question should be "Howto use ColumnDescription objects with data from external sources like google sheet"

Comment: for clarification, in the above working code without google sheets, is that the desired chart? you just can't get the data in that format from the sheet?

Comment: @WhiteHat, that working chart without google sheets is pretty much the desired chart with minimal data .